# Simplest way to concatenate two strings in robot framework .?

Tags: python, robotframework, robotframework-ide

Given two strings 'a' , 'b', what is the simplest way to concatenate them and assign to a new variable in robot framework.?

I tried this simple pythonic way, but it didn't work

```
${var}= 'a' + 'b'
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [Catenate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Catenate) from `BuiltIn`.

Example from docs:

```
${str1} =   Catenate    Hello   world   
${str2} =   Catenate    SEPARATOR=---   Hello   world
${str3} =   Catenate    SEPARATOR=  Hello   world
=>
${str1} = 'Hello world'
${str2} = 'Hello---world'
${str3} = 'Helloworld'
```

Comment: When I was trying to find a keyword for this purpose I kept looking for `Concatenate` and couldn't find it. I ended up using `Format String` at first before finding out the keyword name was just _Catenate_ without the _con_.

Answer (score 21):

`Catenate` is the usual way to go with strings, as pointed in the other answer.
Alternative option is to use just `Set Variable`:

```
${a}=    Set Variable   First
${b}=    Set Variable   Second

${c}=    Set Variable   ${a}${b}
Log To Console    ${c}    # prints FirstSecond

${c}=    Set Variable   ${a} ${b}
Log To Console    ${c}    # prints First Second

${c}=    Set Variable   ${a}-/-${b}
Log To Console    ${c}    # prints First-/-Second
```

The explaination is that the RF processing of any keyword's arguments - `Set Variable` including, goes through substituting any variable with its value. E.g. for this call:

```
Set Variable   ${a}-/-${b}
```

What roughly happens is "the end value is *the value of variable `a`*-/-*the value of variable `b`*".

Answer (score 2):

In `Variable` part, I used the most simple interpolation

```
${a}   Hello
${b}   World
${c}   ${a}${b}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to assign the result to a variable that you use only once, you could instead do an inline expression e.g. using Python's `str.join()`, directly where you would use that variable. `Catenate` ultimately uses `str.join()`.

```
${a}  Set Variable  Hello
${b}  Set Variable  World

Some keyword  ${{ " ".join([$a, $b]) }}
Some keyword  ${{ "\n\n".join([$a, $b]) }}
```

> Note: This applies to RF 3.2 and higher.