# What is P${var} in robot framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a robot framework script, but there's a part of it that I don't understand.

```
${inner}=    Testbed Get Something    P${outer}
Set Something    SOMETHING    ${LIST}[P${idx}]
```

So what is the P before ${...} meaning?

Comment: It may used as shorthand for string concatenation. just run you script and check. you can  look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539759/simplest-way-to-concatenate-two-strings-in-robot-framework